# Is it possible to type traditional characters with a pinyin IME in Windows 7?

Tags: pinyin, traditional-characters, input-methods, characters

I am now used to typing Chinese using a pinyin IME from my time in mainland China.

But as far as I know the pinyin IMEs usually generate simplified characters. I'm now in Taiwan and having trouble learning the ways they type here so I'm wondering if there's a way to type in pinyin but generate traditional characters?

I'm using Windows 7 and would prefer to use one of the IMEs included with it. But if none of them will do it then an answer involving downloading another IME would also be OK.

Comment: Yes, it's in language settings. Let me know if you need a walkthrough but if you found one you should be able to find the rest

Comment: @50-3: A walkthrough will gain you at least one upvote and one accept and think of the other people finding your answer by google in the future, as well as just me (-: For instance should I be looking at the PRC or ROC IMEs?

Comment: I'm not home at the moment so anyone reading this feel free to action the above otherwise I will once I get home.

Comment: I input pinyin to get traditional characters, and my settings are Ekaya Input Method and Microsoft New Phonetic IME 2002a.  Choose HanYu Pinyin for keyboard mapping.  Hope that works for you.

Comment: @user2619: I don't seem to have an "Ekaya" IME in my Windows 7. I have a "Microsoft New Phonetic" listed under "Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)" but under its "Keyboard" there is no "HanYu Pinyin" listed. Is that setting somewhere else?

Comment: @user2619: OK it's here: "Tool Menu" from the IME's system tray icon, then the "Properties" menu item. Then the "Keyboard" tab. Finally "Choose your preferred keyboard layout".

Comment: @ hippytrail:  That sounds right.  By the way, to type the vowel sound in 女 (in pinyin, u with an umlaut), you need to type ‘v’ in this system.  I always forget that, but it turns out there’s a stackex question that explains it!

Comment: Sorry, Ekaya is something different, useful for Burmese and some other Myanmar languages.  So ignore that.

Comment: Most IME I used, I use shift+ctrl+f to switch to 繁体（traditional）

Comment: Yes. There are plenty of traditional Chinese users across Taiwan, Hong Kong, etc.

Comment: @phoeagon: Yes but in Taiwan most people don't use Pinyin IMEs, they use other kinds of IME. I don't know about Hong Kong though.

Comment: @einverne: shift+ctrl+f doesn't switch to traditional on "Microsoft Pinyin New Experience Input Style", which seems to be the default one for Windows in mainland China. Could you give us some clues about which IMEs are included in "Most IME you used"?

Comment: @hippietrail Most IME , I mean [谷歌拼音输入法](http://www.google.com/intl/zh-CN/ime/pinyin/)  and most pinyin IME made by Chinese companies.

Comment: @einverne: Ah, I have noticed when I have to use a computer in a hotel or wang-ba that they always seem to have two very similar fancy IMEs with different graphic themes installed. I think one is green and one is purple.

Comment: @hippietrail http://2e.zol-img.com.cn/product/62/242/ceZZAhbROxBqY.jpg  Is it in this picture?

Comment: @einverne: I'm not sure I recognize anything there though. I think it's time to ask a new question about which IMEs are most used!

Comment: @hippietrail Actually, I think most people in China use [搜狗拼音输入法](http://pinyin.sogou.com/) , but I am using 谷歌拼音输入法 . And there are a lot of 拼音输入法 , like 微软拼音输入法,QQ拼音, 百度拼音... They are all pinyin IME and there are other IME like 五笔输入法 that are using strokes to input. And what Taiwanese use are different to what are using in Mainland China. I recommend you to try 谷歌拼音输入法.

Comment: I've gone ahead and asked a specific question about it: [Which IMEs (input method editors) are actually most used in each of PRC, ROC, and Hong Kong?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/5675)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it which I figured out starting from some tips thanks to [user2619](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/3647/user2619) in the comments:

1. Right click on the keyboard/IME icon in the system tray.
2. Select "Settings" from the popup menu.
3. The "Text Services and Input Languages" dialog will appear. Use the "General" tab.
4. Under "Installed services" click on "Add...".
5. Find the section "Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan).
6. Select "Chinese (Traditional) - New Phonetic". Click "OK".
7. Left click on the keyboard/IME icon in the system tray. Select "Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)".
8. Click on the "Tool Menu" icon in the IME's system tray icon. It's the 4th icon to the right of the `CH` icon.
9. Select the "Properties" menu item. Then the "Keyboard" tab.
10. In the section labelled "Choose your preferred keyboard layout", choose "HanYu Pinyin" from the dropdown list.

Now if you are used to the Pinyin IME for simplified Chinese in the PRC the way to select characters is totally different. I haven't figured out that part yet ...

Comment: Sorry only just got to a PC, Chinese (Simplified, PRC) > Chinese (Simplified) - Microsoft Pinyin New Experience Input style. Is what I use to input simplified Chinese. Your steps are correct for windows included traditional :)

Comment: I got to the last step #10 and I didn't have a choice to pick HanYu Pinyin. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Google's Pinyin IME allows you to switch between simplified and traditional characters. 
https://www.google.com/intl/zh-CN/ime/pinyin/

Answer (score 1):

On the Pinyin language bar, click on Tool Menu > Options > Advanced Tab > Character Set to Traditional

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late to the game.

This does not answer the question, in fact, it circumvents it.

I recommend sogou pinyin (搜狗拼音).

There are both versions for Windows and Mac.  By default it's set to the simplified Chinese, but you can switch to the traditional version very easily by pressing "shift+ctrl+f", f for 繁体(fan ti). And press them again to switch back to the simplified output. Or you can change the setting to define your own preferable combination of the switch.

Answer (score 1):

“華師大”

I am using the simplified Chinese IME from Office 2010. This IME is mainly for simplified characters, but traditional Chinese characters also appear in its database. For an **occasional use** of traditional characters, you may have to scroll down several pages to choose a corresponding traditional character.

For an **occasional use** of traditional characters, you can also use Google Translate or Word to convert simplified characters to traditional characters. Note that such conversion can make a few errors, so a manual grammar check is required before the result is used.

Answer (score 0):

I find this link below is useful for tips on configuring Pinyin input for traditional Chinese on Windows 10. This can be done with Microsoft Pinyin (Simplified, China) or Microsoft Bopomofo (Traditional, Taiwan) keyboard. Good luck.

https://www.pinyinjoe.com/windows-10/windows-10-traditional-chinese-pinyin-input-setup.htm