# How to use jyutping as an input method on windows 8.1

Tags: cantonese, input-methods

Is there a way to use Jyutping as the input method on Windows 8.1?

Comment: No, I tried but cpime won't install in windows 8.1

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Cantonese Phonetic IME at http://cpime.hk/. I don't know about specific support for Windows 8.1, but it works on prior versions of Windows.

Comment: yes it works on 8.1
you have to download, extract, and install it.
Then install the Chinese Traditional Keyboard with the Hong Kong SAR. Then go into input options and select CPIME.